# On compact connected components in the complex plane.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, continuum-theory

If $x\in \mathbb{C}$ and $r>0$, denote by $B(x,r)$ the open ball in $\mathbb{C}$ with center $x$ and radius $r$.

Suppose that $A\subset B(0, \rho)$ is compact, and that $A_{0}$ is a connected component of $0$ in $A$.

From this, Can I conclude that there exists a compact subset $K$ that contains $A_{0}$ and with $0\in\mbox{int}(K)$ such that $\partial K \cap A=\emptyset$?

It started like this:

From the compacity of $A_{0}$ it follows that there exists $\delta>0$ and $a_{1}, \cdots, a_{n}\in A_{0}$ such that $A_{0}\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}B(a_{i}, \delta)$, my candidate for $K$ could be $\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}\overline{B(a_{i}, \delta)}$. But,I don't know what I can conclude from there.

About open compact connected subsets we have the following theorem:

*Theorem* (**Sura-Bura**) : Every compact component $A$ of a locally compact (Hausdorff) space $X$ has a neighborhood base in $X$ consisting of open compact susbsets of $X$.

Comment: $K$ open where? Being compact *and* open is difficult in $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Is $K$ supposed to be open in $A_{n_0}$?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, $K$ must be open in $A_{n_0}$.

Comment: Is there any condition for the radius of the disc $D_{\rho}$?

Comment: No, sorry but I don't understand how the radius could influence the result. Could you explain it to me if it's not a bother?

Comment: I don't understant it either. You can always find a $\rho$ big enough that will satisfy the condition.

Comment: This question is confusing. Some $\rho$ always exists first of all. Then what if $A_{n_0}$ is a segment containing $0$ so that $\partial A_{n_0}=C_{n_0}=A_{n_0}$?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, this $\rho$ exists in the hypothesis.

Comment: $C_{n_0}$ is a connected component of $A_{n_0}$ and you are looking for an intermediate connected subset $C_{n_0}\subsetneq K\subset A_{n_0}$(?)

Comment: exactly, with $K$ not meet the boundary of $A_{n_0}$

Comment: @user987, again: $C_{n_0}$ is a *connected component* (i.e. a maximal connected subspace) of $A_{n_0}.$ How can you hope to find some strictly larger connected subspace of $A_{n_0}?$

Comment: Thanks for the observation, I have reformulated my doubt

Comment: The answers to your revised questions are NO and NO. Try to find examples.

Comment: I was thinking about your comment, but unfortunately I can't find an example where both questions are resolved in the negative. Do you have any suggestion about it?